# C# duration of TimeSpan with days using only hours

Tags: c#

I have a simple question but answer just eludes me, I have a simple timespan:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var ts1 = new TimeSpan(4, 14, 32, 17);      
    Console.WriteLine(ts1.TotalHours);
}
```

What I want is a string of a duration of that timespan in hours minutes and seconds, that is for this I wold expect something like:

```
110:32:17
```

I tried total hours but it gave me double, I could parse that double to get evenrything before come and then just add minutes and seconds to string, but surly there is a better way.

Comment: You don't want total hours. Just display "{(ts1.Days * 24 + ts1.Hours):{ts1.Minutes}:{ts1.Seconds}"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no [format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings) for `TotalHours`. But you can use:

```
string result = $"{(int)ts1.TotalHours}:{ts1:mm':'ss}";
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/P6KFuB

Note: delimit literal characters in a timespan format string with the `'` symbol. [Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings?source=recommendations#other-characters)

---

or, if you find this more readable, use what @TJRockefeller posted as a comment:

```
string result = $"{(int)ts1.TotalHours}:{ts1.Minutes}:{ts1.Seconds}";
```

Comment: I was about to post a very similar answer, but my interpolated string was slightly more verbose, but maybe a little easier to read `$"{(int)ts1.TotalHours}:{ts1.Minutes}:{ts1.Seconds}"`

Comment: @TJRockefeller: a good alternative, you're right, timespan format strings are not very intuitive

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it. It may not be the fastest way, but it still works :

```
 var ts1 = new TimeSpan(4, 14, 32, 17);
 //get the hours by doing an euclidian division by 3600
 int hours = (int)ts1.TotalSeconds / 3600;
 //get minutes by taking what remains(which will be seconds) and doing another 
 division but this time by 60
 int minutes = ((int)ts1.TotalSeconds%3600) / 60;
 //taking the remainder of the previous division (it will be seconds)
 int seconds = ((int)ts1.TotalSeconds % 3600)%60;
 string a = hours.ToString()+":"+minutes.ToString()+":"+seconds.ToString();     
 Console.WriteLine(a);
```